# Android - SendBroadcast Overhead

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How significant is the `sendBroadcast` overhead? Is it something to be worried about if I plan on calling it often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends a lot on how many receivers you have. If your app is the only one receiving it, then you shouldn't be worried. The `TIME_TICK` broadcast is sent every minute by the system and the phone's battery still lasts over a week on 100% idle.